# ¿Cómo agregar datos de formulario a mysql mediante PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Que tal estoy intentando agregar usuarios a mi db mediante **PDO**
hasta ahora he visto algunas web con info pero es muy variado

**¿Cuál sería la forma correcta?**

este es mi código...

```
$PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbregistro;charset=UTF8','root','' ); 

    $sql=$sql->prepare("INSERT INTO registro VALUES (:codigo, :nombre, :a_materno, :a_paterno)");
    $sql->bindParam(':codigo',$_POST['codigo']);
    $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
    $sql->bindParam(':a_materno',$_POST['a_materno']);
    $sql->bindParam(':a_paterno',$_POST['a_paterno']);
    $sql->execute();
```

pero no me guarda los datos, no se que parte estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que tienes es que no estas usando la instancia de PDO que estas creando.

La linea:

```
$sql=$sql->prepare("INSERT INTO registro VALUES (:codigo, :nombre, :a_materno, :a_paterno)");
```

Debería ser:

```
$sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO registro(codigo, nombre, a_materno, a_paterno) VALUES (:codigo, :nombre, :a_materno, :a_paterno)");
```

Intenta de nuevo realizando ese cambio.

Comment: gracias por responder, lo he probado y me arroja error..

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Ok, el error es por que no estas definiendo los campos a los que insertas esos datos, prueba con `$sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO registro (codigo, nombre, a_materno, a_paterno) VALUES (:codigo, :nombre, :a_materno, :a_paterno)");` Suponiendo que los campos de la tabla registro esten nombrados asi.

Comment: Muchas gracias juan ahora me funciona bien (Y)

Comment: Ok, de nada, un gusto ayudar a la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te falto agregar lo siguiente:

`$sentencia->bindParam(':identificacion', $_POST['identificacion'],PDO::PARAM_INT); //param_int en caso tal de que tengas como tipo INT el campo identificacionen la bd
$sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);`

PDTA: la clave esta en que agregues el PDO::PARAM_INT o  PDO::PARAM_STR dependiento del tipo que especificaste a los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un código para resolver la pregunta, completo y funcionando a la fecha de hoy, son dos archivos.

La base de datos, se llama `ejercicio1`, la tabla, `usuarios`, y tiene dos campos `identificacion` y `nombre`.

Código de **form.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="identification" /><br></br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Insertar datos" /><br></br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código de **insertar.php**:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=ejercicio1;host=localhost';
$usuario = 'root'
$contrasena = ";
try{
    $con = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena);
    echo 'Conexion OK'
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (identificacion, nombre)")
    VALUES(:identificacion, :nombre)");
    $sentencia->bindParam(':identificacion', $_POST['identificacion']);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $sentencia->execute();  
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Fallo la conexion:'.$e->GetMessage()
}
?>
```

Lo siguiente es una imagen de la base de datos:

[image: Base datos ejercicio1]