# Ejecutar consultas con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy ejecutando consultas con varios `INNER JOIN` de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "SELECT inscritos.id_curso, cursos_abiertos.curso, cursos_abiertos.horario 
    FROM cursos_abiertos 
    INNER JOIN inscritos 
        ON inscritos.id_curso = cursos_abiertos.id 
    WHERE inscritos.id_student = '$id' 
    ORDER BY inscritos.id_curso";

$sql = mysqli_query ($mysqli,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
{
   AQUI MI CONTENIDO DONDE MUESTRO LOS DATOS   
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ejecutarlas de otra forma, con funciones de PHP más nuevas y ya no usar el `mysqli_query` ni el `mysqli_fetch_array` ni el `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

He probado de muchas formas pero así como lo estoy haciendo es que logro mostrar los datos.

Agradecido a quien me oriente.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de las funciones PHP mas nuevas a las que te refieres

Comment: Entiendo que lo que querés usar es un ORM, podrías empezar con RedBeam que es sencillo y no cuesta nada instalarlo.

Comment: AlejandroMedina me refiero a como puedo ejecutar ese tipo de sentencias con nada mas usando query->($query) y con fetch_assoc(), que son funciones un poco mas nuevas que las que estoy usando, o ejecutarlas con sentencias preparadas como las de PHP 7, si estoy preguntando es porque no conozco dichas funciones que sean mejores que las que uso y me eviten inyeccion SQL.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo agregar datos de formulario a mysql mediante PDO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9406/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-datos-de-formulario-a-mysql-mediante-pdo)

Comment: @LuisHenriquez, la libreria [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) es la misma solo que en tu pregunta la estas  usando en estilo [procedimiento](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) y en [tu comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97582/ejecutar-consultas-con-inner-join#comment180457_97582) buscas usarla en estilo [orientando a objeto](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples)

Comment: Exacto @Marcos me explico mejor, en las sentencias simples yo utilizo estilo orientado a objetos, pero en las consultas que hago con INNER JOIN utilizo estilo procedimiento, he intentado usar estilo OO para las consultas con INNER JOIN pero no me muestra los datos, lo que quisiera saber es la forma en que puedo ejecutar una consulta con INNER JOIN en estilo orientado a objetos

Comment: @LuisHenriquez, entonces tu pregunta es otra, es decir, tu quieres saber: "_¿Por que mi consulta no funciona cuando utilizo mysqil orientado a objetos?_" (o algo asi). Te recomiendo que modifiques el titulo y contenido de  tu pregunta, agregues el código que si te funciona y el código que no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para MySQL PHP provee 3 librerias, mysql (obsoleta), mysqli y PDO.

- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) fue incluida en PHP desde la **versión 5.0**.
- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) fue incluida en PHP desde la **versión 5.1**.

Como podemos ver ambas librerias se llevan poco tiempo y no es que una sistituya a la otra, si no que cada una esta diseñada para un [propósito diferente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

### MySQLi

- Proporciona interfaz procedural y orientada a objetos ([interfaz
  dual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)).
- Amplio soporte de funcionalidades de los motores MySQL con
  versión 4.1.3 o superior.
- Soporte para Declaraciones Preparadas.
- Soporte para Múltiples Declaraciones.
- Soporte para Transacciones.
- Solo bases de datos basadas en MySQL.

### PDO (Objetos de Datos de PHP)

- Interfaz solo orientada a objetos.
- Proporciona una capa de abstracción de bases de datos.
- Soporte para Declaraciones Preparadas.
- Soporte para Transacciones.
- **Compatible con miltiples motores de bases de datos** ([lista](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.drivers.php)).

### ORM

Una trecera opción sería utilizar un **[ORM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeo_objeto-relacional)** (mapeo objeto-relacional), existen diversas opciones por ejemplo [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), [Illuminate Database](https://github.com/illuminate/database) ([Eloquent-Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)), entre otros. Estos ORM agregan una capa de abstacción tanto del motor de base de datos como del lenguaje SQL, facilitando la interaccion con bases de datos.

---

### Ejemplos:

### MySQLi (o MySQL mejorada)

**Estilo orientado a objetos**

```
<?php
// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada sakila
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

// comprobar si existe algun error
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

// Realizar una consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

// Ejecutar comprobar si existe algun error
if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
    echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){

    echo "<table>";
    while ($line = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }


}
else{
    echo 'No se encontraron resultados';
    exit;
}

// Liberar resultados
$resultado->free();

// Cerrar la conexión
$mysqli->close();
```

**Consultas preparadas**

```
<?php
// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada sakila
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

// comprobar si existe algún error
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

// Creamos la consulta SQL
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?';
// La preparamos
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
// bindeamos los datos
$stmt->bind_param('i', 5 );
// Ejecutamos la consulta
$stmt->execute();
// Recuperamos los datos
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

// comprobar si devolvio registros
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){

    // Imprimir los resultados en HTML
    echo "<table>";
    while ($line = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

}
else{
    echo 'No se encontraron resultados';
    exit;
}

// Liberar resultados
$resultado->free();

// Cerrar la conexión
$mysqli->close();
```

**Estilo por procedimientos**

```
<?php
// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada sakila
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

// comprobar si existe algun error
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
    exit;
}

// Creamos una consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

// Ejecutar comprobar si existe algun error
if (!$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
    echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
    echo "Errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
    exit;
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){

    echo "<table>";
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }


}
else{
    echo 'No se encontraron resultados';
    exit;
}

// Liberar resultados
mysqli_free_result($resultado);

// Cerrar la conexión
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

**Mezcla de estilos**

[Según el manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php), es posible mezclar los estilos sin mayor problema:

> Es posible cambiar entre los estilos en cualquier momento. No se
> recomienda mezclar los dos estilos por razones de claridad y estilo de
> código.

### PDO (Objetos de Datos de PHP)

```
<?php

// datos de conexión
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$nombre_usuario = 'nombre_usuario';
$contrasena = 'contraseña';
$opciones = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $nombre_usuario, $contrasena, $opciones);

$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?");

// bindear datos y ejecutar
if ( $sentencia->execute(array('mi_id')) ) {

    // Imprimir los resultados en HTML
    echo "<table>";
    while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

// Liberamos resultados
$resultado->free_result();
```

---

> **Nota:** Es indiferente el tipo de consulta que se realice, da igual que
> contenga un JOIN o no, como indicas en tu pregunta. PHP interpreta la
> consulta como un string y le da igual lo que haya escrito en dicho
> string, **la interpretación de la consulta la realiza el motor de base
> de datos**, en estos ejemplo MySQL.

---

> **Inyección SQL:**
> Para evitar **Inyección SQL** lo mas fácil sería utilizando consultas preparadas, puedes encontrar información de [como
> prevenir la Inyección aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias Xerif si que me has entendido y me has aclarado lo que necesitaba. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

No estas slecionando la columna **inscritos.id_students** pero si la tienes en el **WHERE** debes tambier incluir esa coluumna en el **SELECT**, y hacer todo lo que te respondieron acerca de mysqli, pdo, consultas parametrizadas y como evitar la inyeccion sql

Comment: Lo que expones es falso, puedes comprobarlo tu mismo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7890e/3    @Risa__B